# Running py.test on pyc files in distant directory

Tags: pytest

is it possible to run py.test on directory other than current directory, with only *.pyc files present?

I've tried python_files ini setting, and setting root dir. I also need to start py.test from within my script (not using py.test executable).

Relevant part of code are as follows:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
python_files=test_*.pyc

def main_test(args):
    dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return pytest.main(args=[dirname])
```

Where dirname contains directory with myproject module. This is not current working dir. I am also embedding python.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: There is a discussion about this at the moment in a Github issue: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1329